# pandas plot with timestamps on x axis - tick units?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, matplotlib

I have a pandas data frame with datetime values:

```
    Date/Time           Event Value
0   2018-11-15 17:17:49 62
1   2018-11-15 17:27:50 63
2   2018-11-15 17:37:50 64
3   2018-11-15 17:42:49 65
4   2018-11-15 18:17:49 64
5   2018-11-15 19:27:48 65
6   2018-11-15 19:37:48 66
7   2018-11-15 19:47:49 67
8   2018-11-15 19:57:49 68
9   2018-11-15 20:12:49 69

print (tmp.dtypes)

Date/Time      datetime64[ns]
Event Value             int64
```

Charting it looks like this:

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(8,4))
tmp.plot(x='Date/Time',y='Event Value', legend=None, ax=ax1)
```

[image]

The x-axis has been formatted with appropriate dates and times (and can be further formatted using `set_major_formatter`).

Now I want to draw a rectangle on the chart, to highlight a particular time. To do that I need to know the x-positions.

```
print([x for x in ax1.get_xticks()])

[737013.7291666666, 737013.75, 737013.7708333334, 737013.7916666666, 737013.8125, 737013.8333333334]
```

These are indeed the x-values, i.e. if I use them as origins for the rectangle it plots as expected.

```
rect = patches.Rectangle((737013.75,55),.01,100)
ax1.add_patch(rect)
```

[image]

I don't understand where these numbers come from. They're not epoch values, though they look a little bit like them ('737013.75' corresponds to '1970-01-09 07:43:33', which doesn't mean anything to me).

How can I get the x-position on the chart from a Date/Time value in my dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you plot a dataframe with the `x_compat=True` option you can be certain that the units are matplotlib.dates units. Else, pandas may decide some units for you.

Here, pandas uses matplotlib dates units. They are [defined as](https://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html):

> Matplotlib represents dates using floating point numbers specifying the number of days since 0001-01-01 UTC, plus 1. For example, 0001-01-01, 06:00 is 1.25, not 0.25. Values < 1, i.e. dates before 0001-01-01 UTC are not supported.

You are however not expected to calculate those units yourself. Matplotlib provides helper functions

- `matplotlib.dates.date2num`
- `matplotlib.dates.num2date`
- `matplotlib.dates.datestr2num`

which you can use to calculate back and forth between the units.

As an example, `matplotlib.dates.datestr2num("2018-11-15 19:27:48")` gives you `737013.8109722222`.