# Adjust timestamps on x-axis - Matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, time

I am trying to create a `line` `plot` in order of `time`. For the `df` below, the first value appears at `07:00:00` and finishes at `00:00:40`.

But the `timestamps` aren't assigned to the `x-axis` and the `row` after `midnight` is `plotted` first, instead of last.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

d = ({
    'Time' : ['7:00:00','10:30:00','12:40:00','16:25:00','18:30:00','22:40:00','00:40:00'],
    'Value' : [1,2,3,4,5,4,10],           
     })

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

df['Time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Time'])

plt.plot(df['Time'], df['Value'])

plt.show()

print(df)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your timedelta object is being converted to a numerical representation by matplotlib. That's why you aren't getting a date on your x axis. And the plot is going in order. It's just that `'00:40:00'` is less than all the other times so it's being plotted as the left most point.

What you can do instead is use a datetime format to include days, which will indicate that `00:40:00` should come last since it'll fall on the next day. You can also use pandas plotting method for easier formatting:

```
d = ({
    'Time' : ['2019/1/1 7:00:00','2019/1/1 10:30:00','2019/1/1 12:40:00',
              '2019/1/1 16:25:00','2019/1/1 18:30:00','2019/1/1 22:40:00',
              '2019/1/2 00:40:00'],
    'Value' : [1,2,3,4,5,4,10],           
})

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])

df.plot(x='Time', y='Value')
```

[image]

---

Update

To set the tick/tick lables at your time points is a bit tricky. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53354081/pandas-plot-with-timestamps-on-x-axis-tick-units) will give you an idea of how the positioning works. Basically, you'll need to use something like `matplotlib.dates.date2num` to get the numerical representation of datetime:

```
xticks = [matplotlib.dates.date2num(x) for x in df['Time']]
xticklabels = [x.strftime('%H:%M') for x in df['Time']]

ax.set_xticks(xticks)
ax.set_xticklabels(xticklabels)
```

[image]

Comment: This is good @busybear. But I really want to `plot` the `timestamps` on the `x-axis` without `date-time`. Is it possible to display the x-axis as `07:00:00 - 00:00:40` only.

Comment: I updated my post with the relevant info to do that.

Comment: Thank god. I've been looking for this for hours! A bit unrelated, but when trying to do a transformation between coordinate systems, I got all sorts of weird errors. It all came down to this: matplotlib didn't like pandas 'timestamp' datetype on the x axis, so the converters failed. A simple matplotlib.dates.date2num() beforehand solved everything.