# Why can matplotlib not format monthly data

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, format, date-formatting

The formatting of the x-axis works just fine for daily data but fails for monthly data. Then, it just uses 1970 as the base year. Why is that and how can I solve this issue?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.dates as mdates 

# generate time series
# switch between 'M' and 'D'
years = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', periods=rows, freq='D') #'M')
# randomly generated dummy data
np.random.seed(0)
data1 = np.random.randn(len(years))

# put data together
ts1 = pd.Series(data=data1, index=years)
data = {'check': ts1}
df = pd.concat(data, axis=1)

# generate a plot
ax = df.plot(figsize=(20, 5))

# format xaxis
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%Y %b"))
```

### Daily

[image]

### Monthly

[image]

Comment: Add `x_compat=True` to `df.plot(figsize=(20, 5))`

Comment: you set the formatter, but not the locator

Comment: Thank you, that indeed solves it. Where is this argument documented? cannot find it in [pandas.plot](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) nor in [matplotlib.pyplot](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.html)

Comment: @PaulH neither did I for the daily data, did'nt I?

Comment: Most likely a dupe. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53354081/pandas-plot-with-timestamps-on-x-axis-tick-units) a similar question. Or you can look through the results of https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=x_compat